# Atom 1.0 Syndication Feed Icon and Logo Sizes

Tags: image, atom-feed, feed, image-size

The Atom 1.0 specification has the following lines about the icon and logo elements in the feed:

> **icon** - The image SHOULD have an aspect ratio of one (horizontal) to one  (vertical) and SHOULD be suitable for presentation at a small size.
>
> **logo** - The image SHOULD have an aspect ratio of 2 (horizontal) to 1 (vertical).

What is the reccomended size for the icon and logo images that can be used by most Atom feed readers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a blog post discussing just your question http://snook.ca/archives/rss/add_logo_to_feed/:

> The Atom specification details two separate XML elements that can
>   contain a URL to an image: icon and logo. For icon, it indicates that
>   the image should have a 1:1 ratio and should be appropriate for small
>   sizes. Not much more is spelled out, such as appropriate image types.

... And further on ...

> Now, the RSS specification is a little more specific when it comes to possible image sizes.
>
> Maximum value for width is 144, default value is 88.
>   Maximum value for height is 400, default value is 31.

Since feed readers will probably both show ATOM and RSS feeds, this is the ballpark image size they're expecting. So I checked out the FlickR ATOM feed ( http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/groups_discuss.gne?id=34427469792@N01&lang=en-us&format=atom), that uses a 48px square icon. Maybe you could stick to that for you icon. It doesn't supply a logo though.

Comment: Yes, I looked at the Flickr feed also. I will use 48 x 48 for the icon and because logo is twice as wide, 96 x 48 for that.

Comment: It's amazing that Atom 1.0 has so little documentation! It's been around for years now!

Comment: Yes true. But since there's none, all ATOM readers will cannot make assumptions and will be pretty much fine with everything. So maybe - don't spend too much time on this arbitrary decision.